# jQuery resize on both sides

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-resizable

I'll try to make it clear with words : I would like to know if there is a way with jquery-ui-resizable to resize an object on the 4 sides at the same time, so that the center of the object stay at the same position.

Here is the sandbox http://jsfiddle.net/V79Ge/

So, it's quite like the aspectRatio=true, but while I resize the object from one side, it would control the 3 other sides

Thank you for your clues!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is this the effect you're after: **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V79Ge/19/)**.

jQuery:

```
$('#resizeMe').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css({
            'top': parseInt(ui.position.top, 10) + ((ui.originalSize.height - ui.size.height)) / 2,
            'left': parseInt(ui.position.left, 10) + ((ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width)) / 2
        });
    }
});
```

Edit: updated code and jsFiddle to use ui.position and ui.originalSize.

Comment: Nice shot as well! It workds perfectly, I think I would prefer the use of originalSize property... but I may accept it with tests. Thank you!

Comment: Sure, ui.originalSize and ui.position can easily be used instead of the variables I defined. Code and jsFiddle updated.

Comment: Thanks! There are still bugs due to the fact that the div pos is changed while resizing it (so the mouse is not hover the clicked helper on large resizing). Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Played around with your sandbox a bit and got this.

http://jsfiddle.net/V79Ge/17/

```
$('#resizeMe').resizable({
    aspectRatio: true,
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).offset({ top: (ui.originalSize.height-ui.size.height)/2,left:(ui.originalSize.width-ui.size.width)/2});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your current solution seems very nice! A little buggy with big dimensions. I'll try to accept it if I can fix it.

Comment: @Guile Ya... .I just realized that. I think the other solution is more reliable. I'll see if I can fix mine though.

Answer (score 0):

May the handles be what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/V79Ge/1/

Then you'll only have to add the visual feedback to the sides of the box.

Comment: No, he wants the resize origin to be in the middle of the element. This just puts resize handles on all four sides.

Comment: he needs to resize the div so that it's center is always the same, so if you resize one of the sides all of them should be resized for the div to stay in the same center

Comment: Yes, this is not what I was looking for. j08691 and Th0rndike are right : my "resize origin" should be the middle of the div, not the top-left corner.

Comment: What about this? http://jsfiddle.net/V79Ge/14/ It's not exactly the center of the box but it could work for you.

Comment: @Patroklo - Your last example looks just like the first.

Answer (score 0):

I made some updates j08691's example. Now it also works with north-west handle.

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/V79Ge/19/

```
$('#resizeMe').resizable({
aspectRatio: true,
handles: 'all',
resize: function(event, ui) {
    var posTop = parseInt(ui.position.top, 10);
    var posLeft = parseInt(ui.position.left, 10);
    var oPosTop = parseInt(ui.originalPosition.top, 10);
    var pPosLeft = parseInt(ui.originalPosition.left, 10);
    if(posTop == oPosTop && posLeft == pPosLeft)
    {
        $(this).css({
            'top': posTop + ((ui.originalSize.height - ui.size.height)) / 2,
            'left': posLeft + ((ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width)) / 2
        });
    }
    else {
        var width = ui.size.width;
        var height = ui.size.height;
        var oWidth = ui.originalSize.width;
        var oHeight = ui.originalSize.height;
        $(this).css({                   
            'width': width + (width - oWidth),
            'height': height + (height - oHeight)
        });                
    }
}});
```

It still need more development. Not working with all handles.

Answer (score 0):

```
      $(".nodecontainer").each(function () {
            $(this).parent().attr('style', $(this).attr('style'));
            $(this).spectrum({
                showPalette: true,
                change: function (color) {
                    $(this).parent().css('background-color', color.toHexString());
                },
                palette: [
                    ['black', 'white', 'blanchedalmond'],
                    ['rgb(255, 128, 0);', 'hsv 100 70 50', 'lightyellow']
                ]
            })
        });;
        $('.nodecontainer').each(function () {
            $(this).resizable({
                alsoResize: $(this).parent(),
                resize: function (e, ui) {
                    $(this).css("top", 0);
                    $(this).css("left",0);
                    $(this).css("position","relative");
                }
            });
        });
```