# JQueryUI resize from center, handle glitch

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make resizable components that stay horizontally centered when resized.
I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892585/jquery-resize-on-both-sides/9893012#9893012) discussion a solution for the right side. I tried to expend this behaviour to left side. But, I've encountered a strange behaviour with the event handler.

When you resize from the right, it works like a charm. When you resize from the left, it's broken.
I Think that the original event test is in cause.
`var originalTarget = $(event.originalEvent.target).hasClass("ui-resizable-w")`

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TCHdevlp/V79Ge/186/). Just resize the div by the west side from right to left and vice versa, and you will see, sometimes it consider i'm not resizing the element from the west.

May I change my strategy ? look for an other way to distinct where does the resize come from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer: http://jsfiddle.net/V79Ge/187/

I have altered the re-sizing logic as mentioned below & it resolves the issue,

```
$('#resizeMe').resizable({
    handles : 'n, s, e, w',
    resize: function(event, ui) {
        var isLeft = ui.position.left > ui.originalPosition.left;
        if(isLeft){
            $(this).css({
                'left': parseInt(ui.position.left, 10) - ((ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width)) / 2
            });
        } else {
            $(this).css({
                'left': parseInt(ui.position.left, 10) + ((ui.originalSize.width - ui.size.width)) / 2
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The behaviour is correct when the new width is lower than the original one, but not when it's larger. But, I will work on your solution.

Comment: You showed me the path, thx ! I just replaced `<` by `!=` in the test, and it works !